# Is it necessary to call path_put() on error after path_get() in kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, resources, kernel-module

In kernel module, I have code as:

```
path_get(path);
/*Other stuff*/
if(/*some error occurred here*/)
{
    //path_put(path); //Does it need to call here?
    return -1;
}
```

In above code, should we call *path_put()* before return an error code? Which resources released by *path_put()*?

Comment: The source code apparently is in `/fs/namei.c` (something you should tell us). By looking at it you can figure out that `path_get` acquires resources `path_put` releases them similarly. Soure code: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/namei.c

Comment: It means, for every _path\_get()_, _path\_put()_ must be called

Comment: Since `patch_get()` doesn't return anything it can't fail. It means it does something (reference counting) which caller has to revert at the end of the corresponding code block.

Comment: But I think there should be something - _documentation/manual page(s)_ - where these things should be mentioned. I found nothing about this.